# What will happen if I doesn't give column name or commented it in DropIndex method of gorm v2?

Tags: go, go-gorm

In the below code, I have commented the column name. What will happen here. Does it remove the index from all columns if they have?

```
// Drop index for Name field
//db.Migrator().DropIndex(&User{}, "Name")
db.Migrator().DropIndex(&User{}, "idx_name")
```

Comment: `DropIndex` expects the name of the index to be dropped. Do you want to drop a column instead?

Comment: Is there any possibility for multiple columns having the same index?

Comment: Yes, an index can comprise multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

Test the `User` under PostgreSQL

```
type User struct {
    Id     uint64
    Avatar string
    Nickname string `gorm:"index:idx_name"`
    Password string
}
```

---

Your first question

> I doesn't give column name in DropIndex method of gorm v2?

Test codes

```golang
    err = db.Migrator().DropIndex(&User{}, "")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```

error

```
 unterminated quoted identifier at or near """ (SQLSTATE 42601)
```

---

Second question

> commented it in DropIndex method of gorm v2

Test codes

```golang
    //err = db.Migrator().DropIndex(&User{}, "Nickname")
    //if err != nil {
    //  fmt.Println(err)
    //}
    err = db.Migrator().DropIndex(&User{}, "idx_name")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```

Result: the index `idx_name` is deleted from Postgresql successfully

---

Per the source code of `DropIndex`, the `DROP INDEX`  command will be executed here.

```golang
func (m Migrator) DropIndex(value interface{}, name string) error {
    return m.RunWithValue(value, func(stmt *gorm.Statement) error {
        if idx := stmt.Schema.LookIndex(name); idx != nil {
            name = idx.Name
        }

        return m.DB.Exec("DROP INDEX ?", clause.Column{Name: name}).Error
    })
}
```

Even if the `db.Migrator().DropIndex(&User{}, "Nickname")` is comment, the index will be deleted.